# How to select table name in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to select a table name from my MySql database, and write it out on my HTML page.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM sted, attraksjon, reisetips
```

Then I am trying to write out the table names (sted, attraksjon and reisetips) in my HTML code. I tried this, but didnt work.

```
<?php while($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($datasett)) { ?>
    <li id="navigasjon"><a href="nettside.html"><?php echo $rad["sted"]; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Someone help please

Comment: table names do not become part of the recordset in a regular query

Comment: the code makes very little sense. why don't you put these values into array and then just use foreach? why a database is involved here?

Comment: `SHOW TABLES; `

Answer (score -1):

try this

```php
$table_query = 'SHOW TABLES in db_name';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($table_query);
$stmt->execute();
$table_num_result = $stmt->get_result();
while($rows = $table_num_result->fetch_assoc())
{
   $tables = $row['Tables_in_db_name'];

   echo $tables . '<br>';
}
```

this will list out all tables in your database, also replace **db_name** with your database name and `$conn` with your database connection variable.

Comment: okay, where did i go wrong